# How to expose externally Prometheus and Grafana Dashboards which is configured in GKE with google click to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Can somebody please help me to expose externally Prometheus and Grafana Dashboards which is configured in GKE with google click to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, Grafana can either be exposed as a GKE ClusterIP service publicly or alternatively it can be exposed only internally using port forwarding. You should be able to achieve your target by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/grafana/README.md#access-the-grafana-ui). Else please post symptoms and specific questions.

Comment: Yes, That's what I wanted to do. I want to configure ingress and how to do that ?

Comment: ```kubectl patch svc "${APP_INSTANCE_NAME}-grafana" \
  --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
  -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'```